# Numpy - Map data to a matrix based on index location

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matrix

First, I am only assuming Numpy is the best way to do this, but I'm open to other better suited packages (pandas?).  I am looking to map the following data into a matrix format (to eventually display to users).

Input Data:

```
1) {StartDate: datetime.date(2023, 6, 30), EndDate: datetime.date(2025, 6, 30), XCord = 3.5, YVal = 65}
2) {StartDate: datetime.date(2022, 6, 30), EndDate: datetime.date(2023, 6, 30), XCord = 0.5, YVal = 50}
3) {StartDate: datetime.date(2022, 6, 30), EndDate: datetime.date(2023, 9, 30), XCord = 5.5, YVal = 100}
```

With the following requirements

1. YVal in input data will be mapped as the value for all StartDate <= Y <= EndDate
2. Linearly interpolate on any values that fall between index values (both on X-Axis and Y-Axis)
3. For the Y-Axis (date) interpolation, I interpolate based on the difference of the dates.  Ie, assume you have some date_low < date_target < date_high.  I bucket the data based on how many days there are between date_low - date_high, and date_target to date_low.  For example, if date_target fell exactly between two Y-Axis dates, then 50% of the value would be displayed in date_high row.

**Matrix X-Axis values:**

`0 1 2.25 3.5 4 5 6`

**Matrix Y-Values:**

```
[datetime.date(2022, 9, 30)]
[datetime.date(2022, 12, 30)]
[datetime.date(2023, 6, 30)]
[datetime.date(2023, 12, 30)]
[datetime.date(2024, 6, 30)]
[datetime.date(2024, 12, 30)]
[datetime.date(2025, 6, 30)]
```

For each of the respective input data examples above they would show:

Input 1:

| Date | 0 | 1 | 2.25 | 3.5 | 4 | 5 | 6 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| datetime.date(2022, 9, 30) | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| datetime.date(2022, 12, 30) | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| datetime.date(2023, 6, 30) | 0 | 0 | 0 | 65 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| datetime.date(2023, 12, 30) | 0 | 0 | 0 | 65 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| datetime.date(2024, 6, 30) | 0 | 0 | 0 | 65 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| datetime.date(2024, 12, 30) | 0 | 0 | 0 | 65 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| datetime.date(2025, 6, 30) | 0 | 0 | 0 | 65 | 0 | 0 | 0 |

Input 2:

| Date | 0 | 1 | 2.25 | 3.5 | 4 | 5 | 6 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| datetime.date(2022, 9, 30) | 25 | 25 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| datetime.date(2022, 12, 30) | 25 | 25 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| datetime.date(2023, 6, 30) | 25 | 25 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| datetime.date(2023, 12, 30) | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| datetime.date(2024, 6, 30) | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| datetime.date(2024, 12, 30) | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| datetime.date(2025, 6, 30) | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |

Input 3:

| Date | 0 | 1 | 2.25 | 3.5 | 4 | 5 | 6 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| datetime.date(2022, 9, 30) | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 50 | 50 |
| datetime.date(2022, 12, 30) | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 50 | 50 |
| datetime.date(2023, 6, 30) | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 50 | 50 |
| datetime.date(2023, 12, 30) | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 25 | 25 |
| datetime.date(2024, 6, 30) | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| datetime.date(2024, 12, 30) | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| datetime.date(2025, 6, 30) | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |

I'm looking to add these all together in one matrix as the final output.

Thanks so much!

Comment: The examples seem to be inconsistent. Is the date for the bin the upper bound or the lower bound for the bin? If it is the upper bound, then the first example would be wrong, as the datetime.date(2023, 6, 30)-row should be 0 in all columns. If it is the lower bound, then the second example is wrong, as here too the datetime.date(2023, 6, 30)-row should be 0.

Comment: Thats a good point - and a tricky one to answer.  In reality, my question was kind of broad strokes to whats actually going on.  I would say if anything as it pertains to how I wrote the question, the 'end-date' is the upper bound.
.
In reality, I'm mapping higher frequency (date-wise) data to these more granular buckets.  Using example 2, lets say you had a value of "50"  starting (2022, 6, 30) monthly until (including) (2023, 5, 30).  
.
Sometimes the underlying data rolls monthly, sometimes quarterly.  I hope that helps!  If you have any idea how to incorporate that I'm all ears!! Tx!!!

Comment: The concrete implementation relies a lot on the specifics of the problem at hand. Anyway I think Xarray is the way to go here, pandas would work too, numpy is not really suitable as you can't directly use non-integers like datetime as indices. Is the only goal of bucketing the data to the matrix to display it to the user? If that is the case, I would think that there are better ways to display time-series-data like that.

Comment: Thanks! First time I have seen / heard of xarray, so worth it!   In regards to your question - yes its simply to display data to the user, however its not time-series data.  It's mapping the length of a liability (the 'date axis) and an internal trigger level (top axis) to that liability.  YVal is the liability amount. Does that make sense?

Comment: Is only the length of the liability of interest, or the concrete date as well? If you only want to show the length of the liabilities vs. the liability amount you could show it as a [scatter-plot](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/shapes_and_collections/scatter.html) with the liability-length on the x-Axis and the liability-amount on the y-Axis.

Comment: The concrete dates are of interest as well.  Because as soon as today>one of the date column dates, all those liabilities drop off.  So in this way I can see both length of liabilities and their triggers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using [Xarray](https://docs.xarray.dev/en/stable/).

```
import datetime
import xarray as xr


input_1 = {"StartDate": datetime.date(2023, 6, 30), "EndDate": datetime.date(2025, 6, 30), "XCord": 3.5, "YVal": 65}
input_2 = {"StartDate": datetime.date(2022, 6, 30), "EndDate": datetime.date(2023, 6, 30), "XCord": 0.5, "YVal": 50}
input_3 = {"StartDate": datetime.date(2022, 6, 30), "EndDate": datetime.date(2023, 9, 30), "XCord": 5.5, "YVal": 100}
input_4 = {"StartDate": datetime.date(2023, 2, 15), "EndDate": datetime.date(2025, 2, 15), "XCord": 4.25, "YVal": 100}

Matrix_X_axis_values = [0, 1, 2.25, 3.5, 4, 5, 6]

Matrix_Y_axis_values = [
    datetime.date(2022, 9, 30),
    datetime.date(2022, 12, 30),
    datetime.date(2023, 6, 30),
    datetime.date(2023, 12, 30),
    datetime.date(2024, 6, 30),
    datetime.date(2024, 12, 30),
    datetime.date(2025, 6, 30),
]


def get_neighbour_values(arr, value):
    left_elements = [element for element in arr if element <= value]
    left_neighbour = left_elements[-1] if left_elements else None

    right_elements = [element for element in arr if element > value]
    right_neighbour = right_elements[0] if right_elements else None
    return left_neighbour, right_neighbour


for input_selected in [input_1, input_2, input_3, input_4]:
    foo = xr.DataArray(0, coords=[Matrix_Y_axis_values, Matrix_X_axis_values], dims=["X", "Y"])

    Startdate = input_selected["StartDate"]
    Enddate = input_selected["EndDate"]
    XCord = input_selected["XCord"]
    YVal = input_selected["YVal"]

    interp_startdate_from, interp_startdate_to = get_neighbour_values(Matrix_Y_axis_values, Startdate)
    interp_enddate_from, interp_enddate_to = get_neighbour_values(Matrix_Y_axis_values, Enddate)

    if XCord in Matrix_X_axis_values:
        foo.loc[interp_startdate_to:interp_enddate_to, XCord] = YVal
    else:
        left_XCord, right_XCord = get_neighbour_values(Matrix_X_axis_values, XCord)

        # linear interpolation
        XCord_range = right_XCord - left_XCord
        left_YVal = YVal * (right_XCord - XCord) / XCord_range
        right_YVal = YVal * (XCord - left_XCord) / XCord_range

        foo.loc[interp_startdate_to:interp_enddate_to, left_XCord] = left_YVal
        foo.loc[interp_startdate_to:interp_enddate_to, right_XCord] = right_YVal

    if interp_startdate_to == interp_enddate_to:
        # startdate and Enddate in same bin
        weight = (Enddate - Startdate).days / (interp_startdate_to - interp_startdate_from).days
        foo.loc[interp_startdate_to, :] = foo.loc[interp_startdate_to, :] * weight
    else:
        # Startdate and Enddate in seperate bins
        if interp_startdate_to and interp_startdate_from:
            # date-interpolation for start
            weight = (interp_startdate_to - Startdate).days / (interp_startdate_to - interp_startdate_from).days
            foo.loc[interp_startdate_to, :] = foo.loc[interp_startdate_to, :] * weight

        if interp_enddate_to and interp_enddate_from:
            # date-interpolation for end
            weight = (Enddate - interp_enddate_from).days / (interp_enddate_to - interp_enddate_from).days
            foo.loc[interp_enddate_to, :] = foo.loc[interp_enddate_to, :] * weight

    print(foo)
```

The first example yields a different result compared to your examples. But I'd argue, that it is computed the right way here. I did consider the dates in the table to be the upper bound of the bins.

I did add a fourth example-case to showcase the simultaneous interpolation for X and Y.

Comment: I edited with some more info on Y-axis interpolation / bucketing.

Comment: I have included the weighting for the Y-axis.

Comment: I have refactored the code a bit, now it looks more presentable.